# How to use the Google Analytics API v3 > analytics.management.uploads.uploadData methode in api explorer

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-apis-explorer

i fill in the needed data:
- accountId: 2465955
- webPropertyId: UA-2465955-20
- customDataSourceId: oI7aVdXXRJa_ZA5QNvLkVQ

Request:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/2465955/webproperties/UA-2465955-20/customDataSources/oI7aVdXXRJa_ZA5QNvLkVQ/uploads?fields=customDataSourceId&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

i grant the user access to see and edit data in analytics. after this i get the error:

```
    400

- Hide headers -

cache-control:  private, max-age=0
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  160
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Wed, 05 Sep 2018 09:01:04 GMT
expires:  Wed, 05 Sep 2018 09:01:04 GMT
server:  GSE
vary:  Origin, X-Origin

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest",
    "message": "Upload request URL should start with https://www.googleapis.com/upload/analytics/..."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Upload request URL should start with https://www.googleapis.com/upload/analytics/..."
 }
}
```

i dont know how to send a propper request, hope somone can help me!

thx

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code we cant help you debug what we cant see.

Comment: done, i added the account data in to the form, but i think it wount help.

Comment: How exactly are you sending this HTTP Post?  What are you using to fire it off what you have given me i just just the raw request.   I need to see the code that you are running after submitting your form if thats what your using.

Comment: i use the api explorer ... https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/analytics/v3/analytics.management.uploads.uploadData?accountId=2465955&webPropertyId=UA-2465955-20&customDataSourceId=gx3hqqEjR7qBrcgrIDkToQ&_h=3&

Answer (score 0):

The [Uploads: uploadData](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/uploads/uploadData) method is used to **Upload** data for a custom data source.

You can not use [Google apis exploerer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/analytics/v3/analytics.management.uploads.uploadData) to upload files.  It does not have that functionality it is only meant for testing.

You will need to code this yourself here is a nice example in java directly from the documentation

```
/*
 * Note: This code assumes you have an authorized Analytics service object.
 * See the Data Import Developer Guide for details.
 */


// This request uploads a file for the authorized user.
File file = new File("data.csv");
InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent("application/octet-stream",
    new FileInputStream(file));
mediaContent.setLength(file.length());
try {
  analytics.management().uploads().uploadData("123456",
      "UA-123456-1", "122333444455555", mediaContent).execute();
} catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
  System.err.println("There was a service error: "
      + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
      + e.getDetails().getMessage());
}
```

Comment: i had, but it dont work so i wanted to test the api method with the api explorer. So when this methode dont work at all with the api explorer thx for the hint!

Comment: thx, i added the question with the code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52183820/google-analytics-api-v3-analytics-management-uploads-uploaddata-insufficient-p